# how to fragment packets in c++?

Tags: c++, fragment, packet

I have been implementing the MSEX CITP protocol - with success so far - in my project for streaming image over the network. I'm using winsocks like so:

```
v_id = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(v_id, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char*)&isbroad, sizeof(isbroad));
sendto(v_id, temp_buf, v_buffer->o(), 0, address->get(), socksize);
```

But for image larger than 65k, the spec says that I have to fragment my packets and add a given "preamble".

After some research, from what I understand, I have to set MTU size and fragment header but all my attempts are failing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

`MTU` means `Maximum Transmission Unit`  : it represente the size of the biggest PDU (protocol data unit) that can be sended/received in a one network transaction (generally 1500 bytes for Ethernet).

In your case, it is clear that the size of your data will greatly exceeds the size of MTU. You must therefore send your files in several fragments.

This constraint forces you to explicitly manage:

**1.** The `sending/receiving` of fragments
 **2.** The `reconstruction` of the original file by `concatenating` its different fragments in the `correct order`

To identify and manage your fragments, you must add headers as `meta-data` to your packets. This headers contain for example the size and the sequence number of the fragment:

```
---------------------------  
| headers |       data    |
---------------------------
```

Thanks to these headers, you will know the size of data to read, the sequence number of the fragment. What will allow you to rebuild your image.

Comment: Hey thx for the answer. I don't really need receiving as I'm just sending but I guess it's not the point. But my question is actually more explicitly what are the c++ functions or options I should be playing with to add those headers / meta-data ?

Comment: @user1906731 headers, are NOT protocol fields as this word often means. This is data that you explicitly inject (in buffer) when you build your packages (with memcpy or other variant ..). They are placed in the beginning of the data area of ​​your package mixed with the data of your image. But be careful, the transmitter and the receiver must agree on the size of the headers, otherwise, the receiver will interpret the headers as image data!